# auth()->user() == $profileUser not returning true, although it is true

Tags: laravel

I guess I broke my app somehow as I didn't notice this happened, but I noticed the $profileUser == auth()->user() logic is not working, although it clearly evaluates to true. When I put $profileUser->name == auth()->user->name, it works, but this is not how I want it.

```
Route::get('/profiles/{user}', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile.profile');

public function profile(User $user, ProfilePost $profilePost, $page = null)
{
    $activities = Activity::feed($user);
    $bestReplyCountQuery = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from replies inner join threads on threads.best_reply = replies.id where replies.user_id = '$user->id'"));
    $bestReplyCount = count($bestReplyCountQuery);
    return view('profiles.profile', [
        'profileUser' => $user,
        'activities' => $activities,
        'bestReplyCount' => $bestReplyCount,
    ]);
}

@if($profileUser == auth()->user())
<div class="user-profile-post-init">
    <div class="picture">
        <p class="avatar" style="background-color: {{ $profileUser->color }}">
            {{ substr($profileUser->name, 0, 1) }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-wysiwyg">
        <form method="POST" action="/profiles/{{ $profileUser->name }}/posts">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="text" placeholder="Update your status...">
            <i class="fas fa-pen pen"></i>
            <div class="form-trigger">
                <textarea name="body" id="user-profile-textarea"></textarea>
                <button class="submit" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-reply"></i> Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: your question is not clear! whats your problem excatly? if you have error please post it

Comment: $profileUser is == to auth()->user(), but it is evaluating to false.

Comment: are you sure you are logged in? return auth()->user() and see whats returning